# Safe change of field type from text to email or link

Tags: entities, migrations

I have some field types that are in text and have data and I need them to be a link or email type (ie. email module.) I realize there are several approaches:
change in D7 database.
Use the migration module.
Export as Feature and re-import.

Does someone have experience addressing this and a suggested approach?

Comment: Clarification - I'm a system builder - I Would like to do this without programming.  Concerned about using a low / level or raw function that does not explicitly describe use case of text conversion.

Comment: The node export or views data export (or migration) are all valid approaches and worked ... however the most elegant is @Naveen Valecha who suggested using the helper module. Since it is a utility I was afraid that something might break under the hood and opted for this workaround.

Comment: Too bad nobody created a module to do this using helper!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different approach  could be - Why try to change field type ? Why not copy old to new ?

You could possibly use something like [views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) or other similar module to create a dump of your nodes as node ID and text field to csv file.

Then create your new field.

Then use [feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) to import your csv and assign the old text field column to your new field. Make sure you tick the box to update nodes !

Then delete your old field.

Comment: yes, that is how I approached it.  I then needed to delete the old field, rename the new and change the formatters.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [db_change_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_change_field/7).
See the similar [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/101840/7831) given by [heddn](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/25941/heddn)

Comment: Thanks - pls see comment above.  Was hoping for a method for a system builder rather than developer.... but this may be a good fallback..

Comment: As Davereid Specified here http://www.innoraft.com/blog/change-field-type-data-text#comment-1585508095 that the wrote some code in Helper mdoule(https://www.drupal.org/project/helper). To be frank I have not used this module before.if you want to take a look then you can :) and if that worked then also let us know.