# Is it possible to convert a text field to an email type field that has exiting data in Drupal 9?

Tags: entities

We have a Drupal 9 site that has a plain text field with existing data that was used for email data. We'd like to convert this field type to email. Is this possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I move content from one field to another?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197244/how-do-i-move-content-from-one-field-to-another)

Comment: In this case, the easiest way is to create a new field of the email type and then move the data over.  If you try to convert the field manually, many bad things will happen; it's much easier to create a new field and move your data to that, then delete the old field.

Comment: That page's info seems to be for D7 and is for moving data to a new field, not converting an existing field's type. Thank you though.

Comment: Generally you cannot convert field types without high risk of something going wrong.  So this is the same approach you want to take in Drupal 9-- create a new field, and copy the data over.

Comment: Patrick is right. You will find it easy to just create a new field and copy data into it. If your concern is about the machine name, you can do it in a 2-steps process: 1) rename text field to something different; 2) create new field using old machine name & copy data into it. On the other side, as they are just configuration, have you tried to do a drush cex, change the field type and then do a drush cim?

Comment: Thank you guys - I'll create the new field and migrate the data.